# Maven Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, maven

I want a simple android hello world program in with maven.here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>appzoyfoo141</groupId>
    <artifactId>ekanta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>ekanta</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.1.1</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                        <path>${ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But while trying to run the pom.xml rightclick pom.xml->runas->maven test..getting this error

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2`..Can anybody plz help me..thanks  i am getting this error in console`[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.613s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 09 14:47:46 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project ekanta: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using <sdk><path>...</path></sdk> or <properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties> or on command-line using -Dandroid.sdk.path=... or by setting environment variable ANDROID_HOME -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`
```

Comment: my guess would be that maven is not replacing the ${ANDROID_HOME} property in your pom, and that this is therefore not a valid path hence the exception. Try either setting `ANDROID_HOME` as an environment variable (so outside of maven) and then remove the `<path>` configuration of the plugin in your pom completely or change the `<path>` configuration in your pom to point to the location of the android sdk explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with the com.jayway.maven plugin when trying to build Android Bootstrap project.
I was able to fix this by going into pom.xml properties section and adding my ANDROID sdk path.

```
<properties>
    <abs.version>4.3.1</abs.version>
    <dagger.version>1.0.1</dagger.version>
    <otto.version>1.3.4</otto.version>
    <gson.version>2.2.4</gson.version>
    <menudrawer.version>3.0.2</menudrawer.version>
    <android.sdk.path>C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk</android.sdk.path>
</properties>
```

I originally had it pointing to my JAVA SDK which was causing it to fail -- you need to point this to your ANDROID sdk.

Answer (score -1):

This path is not set: `ANDROID_HOME` and your SDK may be too low a version. And then after  setting.xml set full path android sdk.

Comment: What is `setting.xml`? Please elaborate.