# NullPointerException when trying build a android application with maven and plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, jayway

I am trying building a android application with maven and this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.kleber</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version> 4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.2</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>avd</avd>
                    </emulator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and keeping getting this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.213 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-25T22:03:34-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project app: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.9.0-rc.2:generate-sources failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Anyone can tell what's the problem here?

Comment: see here:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437006/5167517)

Comment: @DoubleCui that not solve the problem (i think the android-maven-plugin is picking the ANDROID_HOME without problem, because when i do set up that I get an error, when I set up the error vanishes).